# "Theoretical computer science" or "theoretical *in* computer science"

Tags: discussion, scope

Sometimes we get questions which are "theoretical questions *in* computer science", but are not "theoretical computer science" questions. Other areas in computer science (e.g. computer networks, ...) also sometimes study theoretical questions (formulated in rigorous mathematics).

Although these questions are not typical topics in theoretical computer science, they are theoretical questions that a theoretical computer scientist may find interesting and can answer. So I don't think being welcoming to them will cause a problem. What do you think?

ps: obviously the usual research level criteria would still apply to them, e.g. if the question is of the level of a typical undergrad course/textbook exercise then it will be off-topic.

Comment: I am not getting it: can you give an example?

Comment: I'd prefer an example as well. I often find that these kinds of abstract policy issues are easier to review in the context of specific questions. In general though, I think questions of the kind described above are perfectly welcome: this reminds me of our discussion on questions about modelling.

Comment: I think Kaveh might be referring to the following question: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7605/surveys-on-network-coding  since he used similar words in a comment he posted there around the same time he asked this question. I think the topic of that question is in scope, but the specific question is a poor one. It is one of the "here's a big field, can you tell me the best reference". Although, I guess such questions are fine on cstheory, they are not ones I enjoy.

Comment: @Artem Kaznatcheev: yes, that was the most recent example, but we had a number of similar cases previously.

Comment: how about this example: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/427/what-are-some-real-world-applications-for-genetic-algorithms

Comment: @Marcos Villagra: I think that question is on-topic (although it is not a good question, it is very unfocused).